# In Excel (VBA) how can I hide worksheets based on values in table column

Tags: excel, vba

I have spreadsheet with around 20 worksheets. On one of the worksheets I have a one column table called CategoriesTable. In this table I want to input the names of the worksheets that I want to remain visible then use VBA to hide the rest.

I can kind of achieve this by adding another column and putting in a value of something like hidden or unhide but I was hoping someone could help with a more efficient way of doing this with just the one column.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub HideSheetsFromColumn()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, El, mtch
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet keeping the sheets to not be hide
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row. If not A:A column, use here the appropriate letter
   arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value
   
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            mtch = Application.match(ws.Name, arr, 0)
            If IsError(mtch) Then 'not found in the list
                ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            Else
                ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'for the case you change your mind and delete the name from the range...
            End If
        Next ws
End Sub
```

You must know that I made an exception and post an answer. Please, note the **it is mandatory to prove that you tried something by your own** and ask as in case your attempt does not work as you need...

Comment: @simonc Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: I've just tested tested it now and it does exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.